# Does 12v 5A power supply is okay to operate motor shield external power

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

[image: My motor]I am new to arduino.
[image: Motor Shield DK Electronics v1.0]
Recently purchased motor shield V1.0 which have two l293 and can run 4 DC motors simultaneously.
But here the problem comes: when I purchased the shield I was not aware that it can only supply 2A peak current.
However, my DC motor rating is 12v 5A. So I purchased a 12v 5A power supply.
But now I am not sure to operate shield with external power of 12v 5A.

Does it works or will it burn?

Comment: It looks very much like [this motor](http://www.vegarobokit.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=35_36&product_id=102) which isn't 5A - it's 300mA. Where did you get the idea of 5A from?

Comment: @Majenko actually it is written in motor 125A , so the shop owner told me that it is 12V and 5A motor

Comment: Well, my eyes don't lie to me - there is no 5A motor from Vega Robot Kit - certainly not in that style. So the shop keeper probably has no clue what he is talking about.

Comment: Thanks @Majenko, I understood your point of view.
So now I what should I use to power my motors, I tried the computer usb to arduino and placed the jumper so its moving slowly at 255 speed and 64 frequency

Comment: You can use your 12V 5A power supply and your motor shield. The motor should never draw more than 300mA, which is far less than both the motor shield and the power supply.

Comment: You mean to say remove that jumper and connect the power supply to motor shield directly

Comment: Yes. The motor needs 12V. You have to power the shield with 12V so the motor can get that 12V it needs.

Comment: So my motor shield will not burn by supplying 12V 5A external power supply?

Comment: @Majenko please reply

Comment: Only if you try and use more current than the shield can cope with. The 5A for the supply is the *maximum it **can** supply, not what it **will** supply*. The current draw is determined by the load, *not the supply*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shield will "burn". You need a shield that can provide minimum 5A *per channel* to run a 5A motor.

However, your motors *aren't 5A*. They have a stall current of 300mA, which is well within the capabilities of the motor shield, and the 5A power supply you have would barely even notice they were there.

Comment: What if the 5A is the average current ? If the stall current is 50A, then a motor driver of 50A is required.

Comment: @Jot We can only go by what we are told by the OP...

Comment: I updated my question, please review and provide appropriate answer

Comment: @Majenko please review my question

Comment: UmarAta, thanks for the photos. I think that is a 12V motor with 60mA or 70mA without load and 300mA stall current. Why do you think it is 5A ? Do you have specifications for that motor ?